# Xamarin.Forms Sending/Receiving MSGs through Bluetooth and Serial Port

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, xamarin.forms

i have a handheld that will be Win10 and another as Android and i want to create an App using Xamarin.Forms to send/ receive MSGs through bluetooth and Serial Port.

so can anyone guide me to the right plugins/tools that i'll need to achieve this target.

Answer (score 0):

Please study serial port profile in bluetooth and you will find all the answers.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.